# Grails GORM MissingMethodException with 1:N relationship

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have such domain classes:

```
class ServicesGroup {
    Long id
    String name
    String description

    String toString(){
        return name
    }

    static mapping = {
        version false
        table 'root.services_groups'

        id column:'group_id' 
        name column:'group_name'
        description column:'group_desc'
    }
}
```

and

```
class Step {
    Long id
    ServicesGroup service
    String stepType
    Integer stepFrom
    Integer stepTo

    static constraints = {
        stepType(inList:['operator', 'client'])
    }

    static mapping = {
        version false
        table 'bill.steps'
        service column:'service_group_id'
    }
}
```

The relationship is - one ServicesGroup entry can have multiple Step instances.

However, when in my controller I try to

```
Step.findByService(3)
```

I get:

```
"org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Step.findByService() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: {3}"
```

However, when I change Step domain class field

```
ServicesGroup service
```

to simply

```
Long service
```

it works.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it that way:

```
Step.findByService(ServicesGroup.get(3))
```

Comment: That works! Can you give my some pointers as to why?

Something in the lines of.. service field is declared as ServicesGroup object, therefore if I want to search for stuff using service, I must use the object of given type?

Is there any more direct way of achieving the same result without nesting findBy*/get?

Thanks!

Comment: See other answer below. A third way would be to use Hibernate criteria and do Step.withCriteria { service { eq("id", 3) } }.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
grails clean
grails run-app
```

Then try again.

Comment: Need to fix in next version. This solution solve many issues not only this.

Answer (score 1):

Something like Step.findByService([id: 3]) may work. It only cares about the ID anyway for the purposes of the SQL generation. In a lot of cases like this you can toss a fake map into there rather than the real thing, and save yourself some performance.

On the other hand, the abstraction breaks down a bit when you do this.